# How to get a value of inner element when clicked on li using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is my li element. I want to get only the value of class 'preview' when clicking on the li element using jquery.

```
<li class="contact">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="contact-status online"></span>
        <img src="" alt="" width="45px" height="45px" />
        <div class="meta">
            <p class="name">John</p>
            <p class="preview">john@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Output should be: john@gmail.com

I tried below code:

```
$('li.contact').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('.preview').val($(this).text());
})
```

Am getting the entire li items click event list as output.

Please help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is using [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) which is wrong to have it here, what you need is to select the `<li>` tag and then perform [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the child `.preview` and then get its text using [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)
This is what you should have in your code:

```js
$('li.contact').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).find('.preview').text();
    console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<li class="contact">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="contact-status online"></span>
        <img src="" alt="" width="45px" height="45px" />
        <div class="meta">
            <p class="name">John</p>
            <p class="preview">john@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It works fine for me. Thanks again,

Comment: You are welcome! if you find it useful please accept it as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to attach the click event handler to each list node, then a few ways could find the child nodes text value, one approach would be using the event.target to get access to the clicked list node, or my approach would be iterating over the list node collection as the following example illustrates.

```js
const theLinkContains = email => document.querySelector('h2 span').textContent = email;

(() =>
{
  document.querySelectorAll('li.contact')
    .forEach(link =>
    {
      link.addEventListener('click', () =>
      {
        theLinkContains(link.querySelector('.preview').textContent);
      });
    });
})();
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.preview {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Result: <span></span></h2>
<ul>
  <li class="contact">
    <div class="wrap">
      <span class="contact-status online"></span>
      <img src="" alt="" width="45px" height="45px" />
      <div class="meta">
        <p class="name">John</p>
        <p class="preview">john@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="contact">
    <div class="wrap">
      <span class="contact-status online"></span>
      <img src="" alt="" width="45px" height="45px" />
      <div class="meta">
        <p class="name">Bob</p>
        <p class="preview">Bob@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to know is this the better to do it in case of performance-wise or it is just another approach.

Comment: Unsure as to how jQuery implements the $ function but if it's running the querySelector method on the `this` object then yes my code would run faster as it already has the reference to the link node.